# Access to SQL link table showing Allow Zero Length as 'Yes'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, database-migration

I have made multiple attempts at creating a SQL Server table to link to an Access front-end with 'disallow zero length value' constraints on the table but when I link the table up to my front-end the design of the table shows **Allow Zero Length** = **Yes**

[image]

Now I have tried various methods of trying to change this to **No** (I need it to be **No** for a migration project I am working on). I am not sure what needs to be done on the SQL Server to ensure that upon linking this table to my access front-end, this constraint is a No.

This is the Create script for my table:

```
Create Table Riku(
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    testtext varchar(255), 

    CONSTRAINT DissalowNulls
    CHECK (testtext <> ''),

    CONSTRAINT DissalowNull2
    CHECK (LEN(testtext) = 0)
);
```

Neither of these two constraints work. I have tried using Nvarchar, Varchar, and Text as SQL Data Type all of which yielded this same result (Yes).
Any ideas?

Comment: If running from SQL side :  First '' (empty string)   is not the same as NULL.  If your table create is SQL side you just have testtext varchar(255) NOT NULL  and you cant put constraints inside the create table script.

Comment: @Brad I get that empty string isn't the same as NULL. I am testing this in a completely empty table on SQL and creating the constraints inside the create table script did infact create them.

Comment: What do you mean "neither of these two constraints work"?   Your `DissalowNulls` constraint alone should do what you seem to be asking.   What was wrong with it?

Comment: As in the Allow Zero Length is still yes within access with constraints on the field.

Comment: but if you allows nulls and bind that column, then you NEVER get ZLS, you get a null. So as a general rule I don't bother or worry. Of course for all my Access applications I never use or allow ZLS - so migration of such data is thus never a issue. If you keep out ZLS then you don't need that constraint and bound text boxes to such columns will store nulls if allowed.

Comment: But this is my problem see. My fields allow nulls. There are even multiple records on the access field that have null values with the access property for ZLS (allow zero length) set to 'No'. Now when I migrate this exact data onto SQL Server using either SSMA or SSMS import, this property automatically changes to Yes. The data is still the same Nulls are still allowed, however zero length strings are now set to 'Yes'.

Answer (score 0):

You must indicate to the column that does not allow null

```
Create Table Riku(
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    testtext varchar(255) NOT NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT DissalowNulls
    CHECK (testtext <> '')
);
```

Comment: I am doing within the check statement. The constraint is there, its just not showing inside MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting your question as:

> "Why is it when I create a constraint in SQL Server to 'DisalowNulls'
>   does it not appear that way when viewing the table properties in
>   Access?"

My answer to that questions is, "they are not syntax equivalent features".  When Access interprets the design of the linked table it is not perceiving these as the same property.  The constraint you created in SQL Server is more equivalent to an Access *Validation Rule* although that will also not appear in the Access table designer.

It would be nice if Access would disable properties that aren't relevant to the database type of the linked table.  Other properties like `Format`, `Input Mask`, and `Caption` could also be in that category.